# How to bypass email activation when performing load testing in jmeter

Tags: email, jmeter, performance-testing, activation-codes

I am trying to perform load testing in JMeter and my application is having an email verification step prior to login.

I have captured test script using script recorder and there is registration request, activation request and login request in the same order as mentioned.An activation link will be sent to the registered email and this link is unique for each user.we can log in to the app only after visiting this link and activating.

So the problem I encounter over here is if I am running this test script using the data supplied from the csv then the activation link doesn't change dynamically and error "invalid activation link" appears.  How can I overcome this problem? unless the activation is completed I cannot login to the application.Please help me to resolve this issue.
If this is not possible then is there any way by which we can bypass the activation process and log in directly after registration using JMeter.

Comment: Talk to your devs...

Comment: Does activation link save in DB? Can you get it using select or other API call?

Answer (score 1):

You can extract the activation link using [Mail Reader sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Mail_Reader_Sampler) and [Regular Expression Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor) combination like:

- **HTTP Request** - to register
- **Mail Reader Sampler** - to get email

  - **Regular Expression Extractor** - to extract link from the email
- another **HTTP Request** to continue registration
- all other stuff

See [How to Create a JMeter Script to Check Email During Registration AND Grab the Confirmation URL](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-create-jmeter-script-check-email-during-registration-and-grab-confirmation-url) article for detailed instructions